# text overlapping in combobox Ext JS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs

the store related to my combobox contains long lines of text and i want this text to be cut according to the width of combobox not overlapping with new lines.

like this: This is a very lon...

so far i get:

```
xtype: 'ProcessTypeCombo',
margins: '0 0 5px 0',
fieldLabel: 'Type',
anchor: '100%',
itemId: 'operationTypeCombo',
allowBlank: false
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xtemplate to format and display long lines, sample fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/t3

(Change the 'length' parameter of ellipsis function in the given sample to suit your need)